# Unable to bind isVisible for input field to model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Here's the jsfiddle showing what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jdivock/ymgwh/1/

On the main app I'm trying to bind input and select fields to show/hide depending on whether or not a checkbox is selected. Sounds easy right? I'm confused as to why this won't work. I can set a disabledBinding no problem, and isVisible seems to work just fine when it's hardcode, but if I bind it to a field in the model . . . no dice.

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
    {{#each App.people}}
        <li>{{name}}<br/> disabled: {{disabled}} <br/>visible: {{visible}}<br/> {{view Ember.TextField disabledBinding="disabled" isVisible="visible"}}<br/><br/></li>
    {{/each}}
        <li>Hardcoded isVisible to false - <br/>{{view Ember.TextField disabledBinding=false isVisible=false}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

js:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create();
App.store = DS.Store.create({revision: 3, adapter: App.adapter});


App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    visible: DS.attr('boolean'),
    disabled: DS.attr('boolean')
})


App.person1 = App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {id: 1, name: 'Disabled', disabled: true, visible: true})
App.person2 = App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {id: 2, name: 'Hidden (supposed to be)', disabled: false, visible: false})
App.person3 = App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {id: 3, name: 'Normal', disabled: false, visible: true})

App.people = App.store.findAll(App.Person)
```

Comment: which version of ember and ember-data are you using?

Comment: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6, ember-data: 0.13. There are older versions in the jsfiddle since I had to dig up an old example as a starting point just to get something up. Still happens in both.

Comment: Eh, got around it by just wrapping the content I needed in good ole fashioned {{if}} tags, seems like isVisible should work though . . . right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you'd just made a small omission.

You've used a binding for `disabled` but not for `isVisible`.

```
{{view Ember.TextField disabledBinding=false isVisible=false}}
```

should be

```
{{view Ember.TextField disabledBinding=false isVisibleBinding=false}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27R99/

Comment: Wierd, I could've sworn I tried that, but lo and behold there it is. Thanks.